# Breaking for loop inside ajax response

Tags: jquery, ajax, for-loop, break

Okey i am making progress bar for sent messages! I need to break out of foor loop inside ajax request response! Here is the code:

```
var breakFlag = false;
loop:
for (var i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    name = userArr[i]['fName'];
    surname = userArr[i]['lName'];
    phone = userArr[i]['phone'];
    counter = i;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: HTTPS + '/lib/model/data/ctlSms.php?send=1',
        data: {
            smsMessage: $("#smsMessage").val(),
            smsClient: $("#smsClient").val(),
            number: $("#number").val(),
            throttle: $("#throttle").val(),
            userPhone: phone,
            fName: name,
            lName: surname,
            counter: counter
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(info) {
            if (info['results'] == "success") {
                if (start) {
                    $("#progress").width(progress);
                    $("#messageArea").append(info['info']);
                    start = false;
                } else {
                    tempPr = $("#progress").width() + progress;
                    $("#messageArea").append(info['info']);
                    $("#progress").width(tempPr);
                }
            } else {
                failed++;
                if (start) {
                    $("#progress").width(progress);
                    $("#messageArea").append(info['info']);
                    start = false;
                } else {
                    tempPr = $("#progress").width() + progress;
                    $("#messageArea").append(info['info']);
                    $("#progress").width(tempPr);
                }
            }
            if ((parseInt(info['counter'])) == count) {
                var success = count - failed;
                $("#messageArea").append("<span>Total of " + count + " messages serviced!</span><br><span style='color:green'>Sucessful: " + success + "</span><br><span style='color:red'>Failed: " + failed + "</span><br>");
            } else if (failed == $("#maxFail").val() && $("#maxFail") != "") {
                var tempCount = info['counter'] + 1;
                $("#messageArea").append("<span>Total of " + tempCount + " messages serviced!</span><br><span style='color:red'>Max failes: " + failed + " reached!</span><br>");
                breakFlag = true;
            }
        },
        error: function() {
            $("#messageArea").append("<span>Ajax error with </span><br>");
        }
    });
    console.log(breakFlag);
    if (breakFlag) {
        console.log("break");
        break loop;
    }
}
```

Okey so i set global var breakFlag to false, and if maximum allowed fails is met, than breakFlag is set to true inside ajax response, and before for loop cycle ends, i check if this flag is set to true... Okey i console loges after setting to true, it says true, but when i check outside response bfore end of cycle its again false, and next xyxle begins??? Why is this happening?

Comment: You can break the loop with return false;

Comment: This does not work... last cycle still is executed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey, i solved my problem! i had not set async to false. After that when everything was frozen i could set flag to true and before cycle ends its saw that it has changed and boke foor loop... :)